# Net neutrality in India

Tags: internet, india, regulations

I'm confused about laws regarding net neutrality in India. However I found some information on Wikipedia article on [Net neutrality in India](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_neutrality_in_India)

Few excerpts from this article —

> *At present, there are no specific legislation regarding Net Neutrality in India.*

> *On 12 July 2018, The Department of Telecommunications made rules, approving the recommendations from TRAI, which heavily favoured net neutrality in India.*

> *Since 12 July 2018 Net Neutrality has been in effect in India. These rules ban any form of data discrimination. ISPs which violate these rules can have their licenses cancelled.*

#### Questions

- Under which legislation these rules are framed?
- How government(s) monitor ISPs if they're following net neutrality?

Answer (score 1):

[Try decides it for India](https://cyberbrics.info/net-neutrality-in-india-from-rules-to-enforcement/)

> ......
> However, Section 11(b)(i) of the TRAI Act, 1997 makes it
> clear that one of the functions of TRAI is to “ensure compliance of
> terms and conditions of license”. In addition, TRAI also has the
> powers, under Section 12 and 13 of the TRAI Act,
> .........

> Unlike the tariff regulation of 2016, which TRAI itself is responsible
> for enforcing, the broader net neutrality framework was brought about
> through amendments to the licences agreements that are entered into
> between the Government and each ISP. Accordingly, the Department of
> Telecommunications (DoT), as the executor of these agreements,
> declared that it would be the one responsible for monitoring and
> enforcement. However, Section 11(b)(i) of the TRAI Act, 1997 makes it
> clear that one of the functions of TRAI is to “ensure compliance of
> terms and conditions of license”. In addition, TRAI also has the
> powers, under Section 12 and 13 of the TRAI Act, to call for any
> information or explanation from service providers and issue directions
> to them.
>
> This illustrates India’s complex regulatory structure in the
> telecommunications sector, with a division of responsibilities
> between DoT and TRAI. While DoT’s intention appears to be to reserve
> the monitoring of net neutrality violations for itself, this cannot
> override TRAI’s statutory functions. Accordingly, the position that
> emerges is that TRAI is also responsible for monitoring quality of
> service and traffic management practices (TMPs), in addition to
> putting in place appropriate disclosure and transparency norms. The
> law, however, does not empower it to impose penalties for violation of
> the licence conditions. Any enforcement action against an observed net
> neutrality violation can therefore be implemented only by DoT.

[IFF enforecement structure](https://internetfreedom.in/what-the-block-our-net-neutrality-rules-require-a-monitoring-and-enforcement-structure/)

> ......................................................................
> Updated Summary
> Over the month, the number of reports provided to us has seen a
> considerable increase now standing at a total of 171 responses of
> blocking, beginning January, 2019 to March 8, 2019. A large portion of
> our findings are mobile internet users at 62.9% while 29.3% are wired
> connections, graphically represented below as well. Reports show that
> blockings conducted by Hathway have begun more recently over the past
> month and a half restricting access to Proxy Services, Virtual Private
> Networks and majorly the Telegram website. Over the past few days,
> there have been increasing complaints against Jio for the blocking of
> Reddit in cities ranging from Bangalore, Chennai, to Pune and Noida.
> ....................................

**Is it a violation, you ask?**

> This blocking trend has raised significant concerns regarding its
> impact on net neutrality. The fundamental aspect in maintaining net
> neutrality is the equal treatment of all data with no restriction on
> the access choices of the user. The Department of Telecommunication in
> the amendments it carried out, aim to ensure this. Ideally, this
> created a prohibition on internet service providers from either
> speeding up, slowing down, restricting choice, bandwidth and the
> ability to access anything on the Internet.

so clearly DOT, TRAI and IFF deal with net neutrality.